# How to store properties of a neo4j node as an array?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on an HR analytics projects using neo4j and I encountered a complicated query (I am also very new to cypher). Basically, I have a list of employee with some features like location, skill set, education and positions with location, skills required. I look if location (employee’s location and position’s location) matches and set that score to 1 (0 otherwise). If I have only one open position, the query works fine. However, with more positions the variable gets overwritten with last value of last position. I would imagine putting the node properties in an array but doesn’t seem that cypher has that (deprecated).

https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-property-values

This is the query that I use and I would be grateful if you can help me resolve the issue.  Final goal is to have a score for every employee per a given position and fill the position with the employee with highest score.  Is this even possible on cypher??
Thanks a lot

```
MATCH
  (e:Employee)-[r:FUTURE_POSITION]-> (p:Position {open_status:1}),
  (e)-[h:HAS_DEGREE]-> (d:Degree),
  (e)-[s:HAS_SKILL]-> (n:Personal_Skill)   
WITH r, e,p,d,n,
  CASE WHEN p.position_state = e.home_state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SameStateScore,
  CASE WHEN p.position_city = e.home_city THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SameCityScore,
  CASE WHEN d.name = "College Degree" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasCollegeDegree,
  CASE WHEN n.name = "Management" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasRequiredSkill
SET e.score = SameStateScore + SameCityScore + HasCollegeDegree + HasRequiredSkill
RETURN DISTINCT e.name,p.name, SameStateScore,SameCityScore,HasCollegeDegree,MAX(HasRequiredSkill) AS HasRequiredSkill, e.score
ORDER BY e.score DESC
```

Comment: How to assign a given employee to a given position based max(r.score) and move to the other employee who has a maximum r.score for another position? and so on. Thanks (@cybersam please advise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you used in your question (https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-property-values) is for the **deprecated legacy REST API**. If you want to make HTTP requests to execute Cypher, you can use the new [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/http-api/) instead.

In order to have a separate employee score per position, you should not be storing the score in the `Employee` node, but in the `FUTURE_POSITION` relationship -- since there is a separate relationship per position. So, just use `r.score` instead of `e.score`:

```
MATCH
  (e:Employee)-[r:FUTURE_POSITION]->(p:Position {open_status:1}),
  (e)-[:HAS_DEGREE]-> (d:Degree),
  (e)-[:HAS_SKILL]-> (n:Personal_Skill)
WITH r, e, p,
  CASE WHEN p.position_state = e.home_state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SameStateScore,
  CASE WHEN p.position_city = e.home_city THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SameCityScore,
  CASE WHEN d.name = "College Degree" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasCollegeDegree,
  CASE WHEN n.name = "Management" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasRequiredSkill
SET r.score = SameStateScore + SameCityScore + HasCollegeDegree + HasRequiredSkill
RETURN DISTINCT
  e.name, p.name, SameStateScore, SameCityScore, HasCollegeDegree,
  MAX(HasRequiredSkill) AS HasRequiredSkill, r.score
ORDER BY r.score DESC
```

Also, the `DISTINCT` option may not be needed, as aggregation functions (like `MAX`) already make sure the set of non-aggregated values in the same result row are distinct.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! it worked. I had to WITH r, e,p,d,n, as I was getting errors r not known.

Comment: I tried to vote but I got this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I opened my account today. I will try to do again when I get the 15 reputation. Again thanks a lot

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks

Comment: How to assign a given employee to a given position based max(r.score) and move to the other employee who has a maximum r.score for another position? and so on. Thanks

Comment: Please create a new Question.

Comment: I have created the new question yesterday here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900512/is-it-possible-to-iterate-though-property-of-relationship-cypher). I have managed to assign the position for the employee with max(r.score) and delete that relationship and move to the second one manually but want something automated like a for loop. Thanks a lot