# is it possible to iterate though property of relationship cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is related to this question: [How to store properties of a neo4j node as an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843464/how-to-store-properties-of-a-neo4j-node-as-an-array)
I would like to iterate through a property of a relationship and check max of that value and assign a new relationship of node1 and node2 and delete node1 from the pool and move to the second one. In other words as in the context of my previous question, How to assign a given employee to a given position based max(r.score) and move to the other employee who has a maximum r.score for another position? Thanks

Have this basic query to assign a position for the employee who has a maximum r.score w.r.t position and remove him from pool of candidates. However, I have to run this manually for the second position. Ideally I want something that checks length if available positions and then fills positions with max(r.score) and then stops when all positions are filled. may be returns a report of hired employees...

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[r:FUTURE_POSITION]->(p:Position) 
WITH MAX(r.score) as s  
MATCH (e)-[r]->(p) WHERE r.score = s 
CREATE (e)-[r2:YOUAREHIRED]->(p)
DELETE r
RETURN e.name, s
```

Comment: Please add your current query to the question, with a description of what it does and how it fails to meet your use case.

Comment: I have edited the question with query. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query may work for you:

```
MATCH (:Employee)-[r:FUTURE_POSITION]->(p:Position)
WITH p, COLLECT(r) AS rs
WITH p, REDUCE(t = rs[0], x IN rs[1..] |
  CASE WHEN x.score > t.score THEN x ELSE t END) AS maxR
WITH p, maxR, maxR.score AS maxScore, STARTNODE(maxR) AS e
CREATE (e)-[:YOUAREHIRED]->(p)
DELETE maxR
RETURN p, e.name AS name, maxScore;
```

- The first `WITH` clause collects all the `FUTURE_POSITION` relationships for each `p`.
- The second `WITH` clause obtains, for each `p`, the relationship with the maximum `score`.
- The third `WITH` clause extracts the variables needed by subsequent clauses.
- The `CREATE` clause creates the `YOUAREHIRED` relationship between `e` (the employee with the highest score for a given `p`) and `p`.
- The `DELETE` clause deletes the `FUTURE_POSITION` relationship between `e` and `p`.
- The `RETURN` clause returns each `p`, along with and the `name` of the employee who was just hired for `p`, and his score, `maxScore`.

[UPDATE]

If you want to delete *all* `FUTURE_POSITION` relationships of each `p` node that gets a `YOUAREHIRED` relationship, you can use this slightly different query:

```
MATCH (:Employee)-[r:FUTURE_POSITION]->(p:Position)
WITH p, COLLECT(r) AS rs
WITH p, rs, REDUCE(t = rs[0], x IN rs[1..] |
  CASE WHEN x.score > t.score THEN x ELSE t END) AS maxR
WITH p, rs, maxR.score AS maxScore, STARTNODE(maxR) AS e
CREATE (e)-[:YOUAREHIRED]->(p)
FOREACH(x IN rs | DELETE x)
RETURN p, e.name AS name, maxScore;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. One more thing please. I would like to remove all FUTURE_POSITION between employees who didn't get the position that was just filed. i.e. Delete r between (e) and (p) if  (e)-[:YOUAREHIRED]->(p) exists.

Comment: Wonderful. Please update (:Employee) with (e:Employee). Other than that, your updated query is what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: `(:Employee)` is just fine without assigning it the variable name `e` in the `MATCH` clause. That is because we don't even bother to pass the `Employee` node forward in the subsequent `WITH` clause. And the `e` variable created later on is only assigned to the node for the *hired* person (not every person who had a `FUTURE_POSITION` relationship with `p`).